# CSS issue with ckeditor and active_admin

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, activeadmin

My ckeditor The icons in the WYSIWYG on this page are all messed up.

I have used ckeditor integrate with active_admin.

and in `initialize/active_admin.rb`

```
 config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js'
 config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/init.js'
```

used

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :text, :as => :ckeditor
      f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :value => current_admin_user.public_user_id
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

`active/admin.css.scss`

```
.cke_chrome {
  width: 76% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Bug icon is not displaying properly and coming wrong icon.
[image]

Comment: Try adding this to your `application.rb` file: `config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true`, then restart your Rails server and try again

Comment: @Justin this is already added in my application.rb